# Exclude string from matched result in regex

Tags: regex, regex-group, splunk

I am trying to capture subject from following string but excluding `\r\n` from the matched result using regex. The string:

```
Sep 20 02:00:00 127.0.0.1 TestHost: Info: MID 123456 Subject "[Notification] - System 1234 [hostname] -\r\n SERVICE_STARTED (INFO)"
```

The Expected output should be(Excluding `\r\n`)

```
[Notification] - System 1234 [hostname] - SERVICE_STARTED (INFO)
```

I tried with following regex in regex101

```
Subject [\'\"]?(?<subject>((?:\\r\\n)?.*))[\'\"]?$
```

But it does not yield me the correct result.

Comment: Please note that I don;t have an option to use replace/sub since I have to do this splunk.

Comment: There seems to be a replace function in Splunk. After you get the `subject`, add `| eval result = replace(subject,"[\r\n]+", "")`

Comment: Note you cannot skip chars in the middle of the group when matching. So, you will have to post-process the match this way or the other.

Comment: May be as a workaround, you can identify two matches (groups) and concatenate them after using this regex: `\"(.*)\\r\\n(.*)\"`

Answer (score 1):

> Please note that I don;t have an option to use replace/sub since I have to do this splunk.

Splunk most certainly has ways of replacing values in strings - either by using [`rex`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex) in `sed` mode, or by using [`eval replace()`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/eval)

This regular expression will pull what you're looking for:

```
| rex field=_raw "\"(?<subject>[^\"]+)"
```

Follow it by replacing the `\r\n`:

```
| eval subject=replace(subject,"[\r\n]+","")
```

If that `replace` does not work for you (sometimes those hidden characters show up as sequential whitespace instead), do this:

```
| eval subject=replace(subject,"\s\s+"," ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **:**

```js
const str = 'Sep 20 02:00:00 127.0.0.1 TestHost: Info: MID 123456 Subject "[Notification] - System 1234 [hostname] -\r\n SERVICE_STARTED (INFO)"';

console.log(str.match(/[^(\'\")]*.*[(\'\")$]/g)[1].replace(/[\r\n\'\"]/g, ''));
```

RegEx explanation **:**

`[^(\'\")]` : matches string start with either single quote or double quote.

`*.*` : matches any number of character after the start

`[(\'\")$]` : Used to match the single or double quotes at the end.

As above regex will match the two substrings from the given string, We will fetch the second one and then do the replace for `\r\n` by using [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

Comment: I don't know what language this is in, but it certainly isn't SPL

Comment: @warren Just for the demo I used JavaScript. But My main focus was on providing a `regex` as OP wants the correct `regex` to get the desired result.

Comment: OP wanted a regex *for Splunk* ... not Javascript :)